# Realforce Explorer - you do not have access

Tags: soql

I want to download Real Force Explorer from this [link](https://bitbucket.org/realforceexplorer/real-force-explorer/wiki/Home)

but I can't
[image]

Could somebody have any information when I can find real force explorer download?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Tangentially related and OP posted in the linked Repo which would be the appropriate place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the tool is not being developed any longer and is no longer available to the public

Here is a [Cached](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ePD55B9dVoIJ:https://bitbucket.org/realforceexplorer/real-force-explorer/wiki/Home%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari) version.

If you get to the cached downloads page the AWS Downloads are also forbidden

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  I'm not sure if tool was completely lost https://bitbucket.org/realforceexplorer/real-force-explorer/issues?status=new&status=open Maybe someone have realforce on computer and could share it here ?

Comment: @Adamo - Right but the last time it was worked on by the author was 2014. TLS 1.0 is also an issue. The tool appears dead

Comment: @adamo we are the developers of the Real Force explorer. We are rebooting that tool with much more features and will be released as Datasert Realforce. Currently in beta. Let me know if you want to try. support@datasert.com

Comment: We have released the tool at https://www.datasert.com/products/realforce

Comment: @datasert - Nice but for mac it does not show up in launchpad after copying to Applications and it requires a key to continue after the trial (unknown length) yet there is no pricing information on your website or any info on the license key. Having to launch from finder and lack of transparent licensing information makes it a no go for me at least

Comment: @eric thank you for sharing the thoughts. We are working on licensing integration in the tool. After that licensing information will be added to website (current plan is by Oct 20th). About launchpad, it needs separate signing process for Mac, which we are working on.